# Regex acronym matching and typo correction

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to fix some typos and one common one is a space missing betweens sentences: `"This is a sentence.Here is another sentence."` I want to match and add a space so I wrote this regular expression:

```
var re = /\.(?=[A-Z]|\()/g;
var res = str.replace(re, '. ');
```

That covers the squished together sentences, as well as another typo involving parenthesis which is not important for this question.

The problem is that there are acronyms that show up, which are also matched and (incorrectly) replace. Example: "The U.S. is a country" is replaced to "The U. S. is a country". I'm trying to prevent these acronyms from being matched. I think maybe what I want is a "lookbehind", but javascript doesn't support that.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: regex's are not designed for language context parsing.

Comment: You'd need a unique delimiter for `RegExp` !

Comment: How about "taking a step back" and matching one char before the `"."` and then putting it back when replacing: `var res = str.replace(/([a-z])\.(?=[A-Z]|\()/g.replace(re, '$1. ');`. Of course, this is only valid if your "sentences" always end with a lowercase letter.

Comment: There are cases which you found out, do not work with your regex, because of the definition of the period in the context of Acronyms.  You really need to have some sort of delimiter to catch that sort of thing instead.  That's kinda of odd because you are doing sentences in the US Language, which is pretty erm... how shall i say.... varied, syntactically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
\.(?=[A-Z]|\()(?![A-Z]\.)
```

This ensures the proceeding characters after the "." do not include a capital letter followed by a "."

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
var str = "A sentance.Another sentance with an A.C.R.O.N.Y.M.Yet another sentence."
var re = /\.(?=[A-Z][^.]|\()/g; 
var res = str.replace(re, '. ');
res // => "A sentance. Another sentance with an A.C.R.O.N.Y.M. Yet another sentence."
```